# How to CALayer render context on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation, calayer

I have had `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext` objects already and I want to create an animation on it by `CABasicAnimation`. The problem is I can't control some `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext` objects when it was drawn by `CGContextStrokePath` or `CGContextFillRect` (line, rectangle, circle, ellipse,...).

I want to add `UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext` objects to a layer. How can I do it?

Comment: You can add shapes to `CAShapeLayer`s and then animate those. Instead of drawing with those functions, you'd set the `path` property of the CAShapeLayer and let it handle the drawing.

Comment: Thanks Chris Slowik. I'll try it